# email Html displays blue border

Tags: hyperlink, html-email

Linked image shows a blue border and seperates from email body in Outlook and IE

i tried to insert this style at the top

img
{  border-style: none;
}

Still doesnt work

Answer (score 3):

EDIT

```
img { border: 0; margin:0;}
```

Comment: thanks it helped with the blue box. but the space under the image in outlook 2007 still visible. its basically an invisible line.

Comment: edited code above to include a margin which acts as padding on the outside of the element. Without seeing the code, its impossible to know the exact issue but the edited code above is my best guess.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if border="0" can be added to IMAGE tag maybe depends on your version of HTML 4.1/5 (not in the style, although you can probably leave the  style as it is to style="border-style: none;"

Answer (score 0):

try `display:block;` in your image style tag